# Image is not being shown within the JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing

I've been trying at this for an hour now and for some reason I can't seem to get my image to show on the `JFrame` canvas. I've Googled lots of other questions but none can help. After inputting the image onto the frame I will need to put text over that, but I can do that I just can't seem to get the image shown. Also updated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Meme extends JPanel{
    public BufferedImage img;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generate();
    }

    public static void Generate() {
        //Creating the frame
        JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Meme");
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainframe.setSize(800, 800);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param g
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("pic.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Catching an exception just to ignore it seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

Ughh.. so many problem in this (short) single method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("pic.jpg"));
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

1. The correct method to override for any `JComponent` (or extension of it as in `JPanel`) is `paintComponent(Graphics)`.
2. Any overridden paint method should immediately call the super method to ensure that the BG & borders are painted, therefore erasing any earlier painted elements.
3. Reading an image should never be done in a paint method, which are ***only for painting*** rather than do any 'long running' task such as loading an image. Move that code to a constructor or the `Generate` method (which, BTW, should be lower case first letter, I.E. `generate`)
4. Application resources (such as the image - which I'm guessing is an inherent part of the app.) will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.
5. `} catch (IOException e) { }` Someone above said that seems 'silly' - because it is. The code is ignoring or swalling those very handy stack traces which might help explain the immediate and most relevant problem. Change it to `} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` for more information.

### Edit

I just noticed something else that might be a 'no go' for this code. The `Generate` method is the only thing called from the `main` method. At no point does it create a `Meme` and add it to the frame! What on earth did you *expect* to appear in the frame?

### Edit 2

Here is the above code reworked to include the suggestions above, plus a couple more. **It does not fix *all* the potential problems or include *all* possible optimizations.**

This is the result:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Meme extends JPanel {

    public BufferedImage img;

    Meme() {
        /* This next statement is purely for debugging. If the GUI is not red 
         inside the frame decorations, something is very wrong. */
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        try {
            //img = ImageIO.read(new File("pic.jpg"));
            img = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg"));
            generate();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Meme();
    }

    public void generate() {
        //Creating the frame
        JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Meme");
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainframe.add(this);
        mainframe.setSize(600, 500);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, this);
    }
}
```